# How to make page by page report in XtraReport

Tags: c#, devexpress, report

I add multiple pages dynamically with different datasource. Means each page contain different data So how can I add multiple pages at runtime or dynamically in this XtraReport. 
For example my report look like;
[image]

And for this report should be three reports. It will be seperate like that  Row number  1,2,3 first page;
4,5  second page and 6 third page

Comment: The report merging/combining documentation might be what you want: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument3320

Comment: thnk u for ur answer @Brendon but No it is  not what i want because if u check my example  i dont know how many different data i will have so it is meaning i have n page report.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this task using following ways:

1. You can add reports with different Data Source as [SubReport](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument5175) and use [PageBreak](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIBand_PageBreaktopic).
2. You can merge pages from different report documents to create a single combined report document. Use the reference link specified by Brendon - [Combining Reports](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument3320)

**References:**
[Pagebreak between subreports](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q213741)
[Pagebreak and subreport](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q532043)

Comment: Thank you @NiranjanKala for your answer. But it is not what i am looking. I have one report and data is coming. I want to separete this report by my data. I am editing my question please check it.